# localhost/encrypt returns not found but everything is configured

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, jce

I am new in spring cloud and at this moment I'm tying create simple config server.
Now I am on a encryption step and I have installed JCE in jdk1.8 folder, also I have codes:

***application.yml***

```
server:
  port: 8888
  servlet:
    context-path: /

spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: https://github.com/genadigeno/config-server.git
          search-paths:
            - 'station*'
          repos:
            perf:
              pattern:
                - "*/perf"
              uri: https://github.com/genadigeno/performance-test.git
              search-paths:
                - 'station*'
```

and ***bootstrap.properties***

```
encrypt.key=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWYXZ
```

and I also disabled csrf for post requesting and it works.
The problem is that when I send post request: ***localhost:8888/ecnrypt*** it returns me 404 error code.

this is picture:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your url has a typo: `ecnrypt` should be `encrypt`